# How to convert XML to XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert a xml file to xslt

My xml file is like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="testxsl.xsl"?>
<doc>
<test>
    <field name="id">c8b102</field>
    <field name="created_at">2013-11-14T00:00:00Z</field>
    <field name="userid">userfirst</field>
    <field name="screenname">userfirst</field>
    <field name="status">open</field>
    <field name="contents">testing content</field>
    <field name="sentiment">positive</field>
    <field name="location">placename</field>
    <field name="source">local</field>
    <field name="url">test</field>
    <field name="keyword">test</field>
</test>
<test>
    <field name="id">c8b102</field>
    <field name="created_at">2013-11-14T00:00:00Z</field>
    <field name="userid">usersec</field>
    <field name="screenname">usersec</field>
    <field name="status">close</field>
    <field name="contents">test sec</field>
    <field name="sentiment">positive</field>
    <field name="location">place</field>
    <field name="source">local</field>
    <field name="url">test</field>
    <field name="keyword">test</field>
  </test>
  </doc>
```

I have written a xsl code(testxsl.xsl) for transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Complaints</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Created Date</th>
  <th>UserID</th>
  <th>Screenname</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Contents</th>
  <th>Source</th>
  <th>URL</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="doc/test">
<tr>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="date" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name = 'userid']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='screenname']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='status']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='contents']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='source']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='url']" />
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i am getting only header part in the output with borders and all like below,

```
Created Date  UserID    Screenname  Status  Contents    Source  URL
```

I dont know what is the problem, my xsl file seems to be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element named `date` in your input XML. Likewise, the elements inside `test` are not called `str`, but `field`.

Your XSLT code must of course correspond to the elements in your input XML.

Use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Complaints</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Created Date</th>
  <th>UserID</th>
  <th>Screenname</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Contents</th>
  <th>Source</th>
  <th>URL</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="doc/test">
<tr>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='created_at']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'userid']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='screenname']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='status']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='contents']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='source']" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='url']" />
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Complaints</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Created Date</th>
            <th>UserID</th>
            <th>Screenname</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Contents</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>URL</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>2013-11-14T00:00:00Z</td>
           <td>userfirst</td>
           <td>userfirst</td>
           <td>open</td>
           <td>testing content</td>
           <td>local</td>
           <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <!--...-->
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered HTML**

[image]